# system lock screen shield music

Tags: android, lockscreen, android-launcher, background-music

We are modifying the Android Framework.The launcher is with the background music.Now I modify the system lock screen.When the mobile phone restarts,entering the lock screen status and now play the music of launcher,how do I　shield　the background music?If you my dear friend can help me, I will be very thank you for you.

Comment: what do you mean by shield the background music?

Comment: when it is lock screen status,stopping the music